# Redux saga dispatching action before api response

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am a beginner getting hands dirty on redux and redux-saga. I am making API calls in a saga file. But actions are getting dispatched before  I receive any response from the call.

**rootSaga.js**

```
        import {all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
        import {watchAll} from './todoSaga';

        export default function* rootSaga(){
        yield all([
            watchAll()
        ])
    }
```

**todoSaga.js**

```
import {put, takeLatest, call, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ADD_TODO, GET_TODO, ADD_TODO_SUCCESS,GET_TODO_SUCCESS, DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS,DELETE_TODO,UPDATE_TODO,UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS} from '../Actions/actionTypes';

const BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8002/api";

export function* getTodoSaga(){
    try{
        const response = yield call(axios.get, (`${BaseUrl}/todos`) )
        yield put({type:GET_TODO_SUCCESS,payload:response.data})
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

export function* addTodoSaga(action){
    try{
        const response = yield call(axios.post, (`${BaseUrl}/addtodo`),action.payload )
        yield put({type:ADD_TODO_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

export function* deleteTodoSaga(action){
    try{
        const response = yield call(axios.delete,(`${BaseUrl}/delete/${action.payload}`))
        yield put({type:DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

export function* updateTodoSaga(action){
    try{
        const response = yield call(axios.put,(`${BaseUrl}/update/${action.payload.id}`),action.payload.todo)
        yield put({type:UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})    
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

export function* watchAll(){
    yield all([
        takeLatest(GET_TODO,getTodoSaga),
        takeLatest(DELETE_TODO,deleteTodoSaga),
        takeLatest(ADD_TODO,addTodoSaga),
        takeLatest(UPDATE_TODO,updateTodoSaga)
    ]);
}
```

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const ADD_TODO =  "ADD_TODO"
export const DELETE_TODO = "DELETE_TODO"
export const UPDATE_TODO = "UPDATE_TODO"
export const GET_TODO = "GET_TODO"
export const ADD_TODO_SUCCESS = "ADD_TODO_SUCCESS"
export const DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS = "DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS"
export const UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS = "UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS"
export const GET_TODO_SUCCESS = "GET_TODO_SUCCESS"
export const UPDATE_STATUS_TODO = "UPDATE_STATUS_TODO"
export const UPDATE_STATUS_TODO_SUCCESS = "UPDATE_STATUS_TODO_SUCCESS"
```

**actionCreators.js**

```
  import {ADD_TODO,GET_TODO, DELETE_TODO, UPDATE_TODO,UPDATE_STATUS_TODO} from './actionTypes'

export const getToDo =() =>{
    return{
        type: GET_TODO
    }
}

export const addToDo = (todo) =>{
    return{
        type: ADD_TODO,
        payload: todo
    } 
}

export const deleteToDo = (id) =>{
    return{
        type: DELETE_TODO,
        payload: id
    }
}

export const updateToDo = (id,todo) =>{
    return{
        type: UPDATE_TODO,
        payload: {id,todo}
    }
}

export const updateStatusToDo = (id,completed) =>{
    return{
        type: UPDATE_STATUS_TODO,
        payload:{id,completed}
    }
}
```

I am facing problem only in updateTodoSaga function.

```
yield put({type:UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})
```

get called before I get a response from API call. Also, I tried putting delay but I think there's a better way to do it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You only get that problem in `updateTodoSaga` ?

Comment: yes, functions are working properly

Comment: Can you show where you call it ?

Comment: It's working fine now. I restarted the dev server but still can't figure out what was the problem.

Comment: why you think it's called before response? Maybe store just hold payload from previous update?

Comment: can you share `actionTypes`? How do you define `UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS`?

Comment: @Alex I have added `acionTypes` and `actionCreators`. Though it is working fine now after restarting the dev server